# how to create a paging modal in reactjs

Tags: reactjs

how to create a modal in react js , when i click a btn continue it show the next modal with out closing the modal , this is the code for the modal i'd like to code

```
<Modal 
  show={this.state.show} 
  onHide={this.handleClose} 
  bsSize="large" 
  aria-labelledby="contained-modal-title-lg"
>
  <Modal.Header>
    <Modal.Title className="f2 pa0">welcome modal.</Modal.Title>
  </Modal.Header>
  <Modal.Body>
    <ol>
      <li className="mb-3">hello <strong>There</strong>.</li>
      <li className="mb-3">hi!<b>welcome back</b> <i>MR0B</i> to intro.</li>
    </ol>
    <div className="form-group mt-4">
    </div>
  </Modal.Body>
  <Modal.Footer>
    <Button onClick={this.handleClose}>Close</Button>
    <Button className="link dim mb2 dib white bg-purple pointer">continue</Button>
  </Modal.Footer>
</Modal>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set another state property, which is the number of the page of the modal you are showing.

```
this.state = {
    pageNumber: 0,
}
```

Then use the buttons to manipulate that state:

On Button Forward:

```
this.setState({pageNumber: this.state.pageNumber+1})
```

On Button Back:

```
this.setState({pageNumber: this.state.pageNumber-1})
```

Then in your component body, you can show different pages based on the number:

```
this.state.pageNumber === 0 ? <div> Page 0 (nextButton) </div> : '';
this.state.pageNumber === 1 ? <div> Page 1 (prevButton, nextButton) </div> : '';
this.state.pageNumber === 2 ? <div> Page 2 (prevButton) </div> : '';
```

Hope you got the idea! :)